# What could be causing a duplicate URL hash in history?

Tags: javascript, dojo, browser-history, html5-history

I am using Dojo. The code is rather long and complex, however here's the summary of what is happening:

The page loads, during the construction of the app, the hash gets set programatically with dojo/hash twice, first time to "", second time to "tileName="Y01". After the second change, something is duplicating the last entry at a random point in time, and it doesn't look like it is anything in my code. Basically - right after the second hash change, history reads 3 entries - but if I add a console loop of 500-600 entries, I will see that at a certain point history will read 4 entries, with the last entry as the duplicate of the 3rd entry.

Can anyone shed some light on what could be causing this? It's hard to debug, because that duplication is not even being registered as a "hash change", since it's not actually changing the hash, just duplicating the history entry.